# How to relayout SWT composite container when FigureCanvas is changed?

Tags: layout, event-handling, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I'm using org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.ScrollingGraphicalViewer. When I add an editpart in the model scroll bars appears around GEF canvas. My parent control (SWT composite) could extend to contain whole canvas, but it doesn't get any notifications from it.

How do I propagate relayout from draw2d GEF canvas to SWT container?